# FFmpeg: method DESCRIBE failed - 404 not found

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp

I trying to play RTSP stream from my IP camera by FFmpeg lib.

Here is my code:

```
const char  *filenameSrc = "rtsp://admin:Centic.vn2018@113.176.100.223/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&unicast=true&proto=Onvif"; //Axis
AVDictionary *options = NULL;
av_dict_set(&options,"rtsp_flags","prefer_tcp",0);
av_dict_set(&options,"stimeout","1000000",0);
if ( avformat_open_input( &pFormatCtx, filenameSrc, NULL, &options ) != 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Open File Error 12" << std::endl;
        return -12;
    }
```

I get this error:

```
LBMixtureOfGaussians()
[rtsp @ 0xf22bc0] method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Not Found
Open File Error 12
```

Someone can help me find the reason, thank in advance!

Comment: Seems pretty self explanatory. Whatever you're trying to open, that you have not shown us, isn't where you think it is.

Comment: I am trying to open the RTSP link, as filenameSrc,  you can open it with VLC

Comment: You could use Wireshark to compare the stream from VLC and your code, that should sort things out quickly.

Comment: Thank @RudolfsBundulis, I reinstall FFmpeg and it works.